# ¿Como hacer un botón que redirecciona a otra pagina y activa un cheked en html y java script?

Tags: javascript, html5, botón, input

espero pueda ayudarme, tengo un problema con los botones, lo que quiero lograr es que al hacer clic en el botón, este abra otra pagina de la misma web pero active un cheked con id llamada "servicio", sin embargo solo logro hacer que abra la pagina pero no activa el cheked del input.

Este es el código java que estoy usando en la pagina web donde debe ejecutarse el botón.

```js
function chekedservicio() {
  window.location.href = "directorio.html";
  var x = document(directorio.html).getElementById("servicio");
  x.checked = true;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="chekedservicio()" class="category-item d-block hover-y">Abrir</button>
```

Este es el input que tengo en la otra pagina web, aquí es donde debe activarse el cheked.

```html
<input type="radio" id="serv" name="categories" value="servicio">
```

Comment: javascript solo puede afectar a la pagina donde se ejecuta, no puedes alterar otros sitios web, prueba mandar el ID como un parámetro GET y en la pagina de destino ejecutar otro script que lo lea y active el checkbox correspondiente

Comment: si no quieres añadir parametros a la url con GET puedes hacerlo mediante [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) o [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). De ese modo puedes guardar una clave y un valor en el navegador del visitante y recuperarlos en cualquier página de tu web (no sirve para webs distintas).

Comment: Muchas gracias, tal vez me sea funcional el parametro GET, sin embargo es algo que nunca he utilizado más que en wordpress, saben si hay algún tutorial para eso?